# How to install QT Creator to an external hard drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 lts.

I have tried installing QT Creator 5.3.2 to an external hard drive. When I double click the qtcreator icon/file in QT5.3.2/Tools/QtCreator/bin nothing happens. When I launch the file from the terminal I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Using normal user and super user gives the same result.

Even if I install it to the main hard drive in my home folder it still seg faults.

I have eclipse set up this way and need this ability with qtcreator as I am using multiple locations to do development.

Any ideas from the community on what would resolve this.

Comment: If you move the files to another location besides the external drive does it work?

Comment: I get the same effect if I install it to my home directory that is on the main disk.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a require component installed then, thus, has nothing to do with your external drive.

Comment: Any idea where the list of requirements are on the qt-project site. Have looked but cannot find a good list.

Comment: I don't.   But a segmentation fault is hard to diagnose even with all information.

Comment: The link for for the page that is supposed to have the requirements 404s and they don't have an easy way to get a hold of them. Will have to put this on the back burner for a moment. Will try previous stable version as well.